# How do I get Vim home directory?

Tags: vim

I wanted to set the `VIMHOME` variable this way (common to Windows and Linux),

```
let $VIMHOME=expand("%:p")."/..",
```

so that `VIMHOME` is "~/.vim" in Linux or "path/to/vimfiles" in Windows.

I put this in a `var.vim` file and placed this in the plugin directory.
It loads properly, but VIMHOME is set only to "./..".

How do I get the full path of a file using `expand`?

Is there an easy way to set `VIMHOME`?

**Edit:**
I changed the expression to:

```
let $VIMHOME=expand("<sfile>:p:h")
```

Now, `VIMHOME` is set to "~/.vim/plugin" in Linux.

My requirement is setting VIMHOME to "~/.vim" or "path/to/vimfiles".
But,

```
let $VIMHOME=expand("<sfile>:p:h")
let $VIMHOME=expand("$VIMHOME:p:h")
```

is not working.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Add another `:h`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: oh.. Thanx thats working as well..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put this in your `var.vim` plugin file:

```
let $VIMHOME=expand('<sfile>:p:h:h')
```

`%` in *expand* will refer to the file being edited (i.e. the pathname given on the command line). `<sfile>` will refer to the file being ‘sourced’ (i.e. the plugin or startup file that is active when the expansion is made).

The `:p` modifier makes the pathname absolute and the `:h` suffix drops the last pathname component (i.e. the filename in this case).

Comment: Just a heads up, if you expand('<sfile>') in a function, it will probably not return what you are expecting. The solution is to expand('<sfile>') outside of the function in your script (in a g:sfile variable or something, use :help instance-variables for more info) and then use that variable in the funtion.

Comment: Jaymon's advice really helped after many frustrating hours. Set a global variable outside of a function.

Comment: I think packages are a more recent invention than this answer, but if your plugin script is in .vim/pack/plugins/start, for example, this won't work.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I was looking for,

```
if has('win32') || has ('win64')
    let $VIMHOME = $VIM."/vimfiles"
else
    let $VIMHOME = $HOME."/.vim"
endif
```

Comment: Not always true: some people have vim installed in (and hence $VIM set to) `C:\Program Files\Vim` and the settings in `C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\vimfiles`.  A safe way is to have a file installed in vimfiles and use `globpath(&rtp, filename)`.

Comment: The accepted answer works properly.. thanx

Comment: @asdfg: Your source link http://zd-xp1:8080/ZohoSync/ is bogus.

Comment: I think "hard coding" the location is more practical and reliable than trying to determine it from any file being sourced. Except, for Windows, I'd just swap `$VIM` for `$HOME` or `$USERPROFILE`. I think vim running on Windows sets `$HOME`, making it safe to use, but would have to boot up a Windows machine to be sure.