# Derive vimfiles directory from runtimepath option

Tags: vim, vimrc, cross-platform

I want to set a `$VIMFILES` variable in my `vimrc` file to determine in a non-platform-specific way the file path of my `vimfiles` directory (a la [How do I get Vim home directory?](https://superuser.com/q/119991/199803)). This should be trivial (in fact, I think it should be a built-in variable), but I can't figure out a robust way to do it. The method using a plugin requires you to put any code that actually *uses* this variable in your `after` directory, which (in my opinion) makes the plugin almost useless. The method using `if has` to determine the operating system and manually set the variable seems absurdly fragile and tedious.

So I'd like to just make the assumption that the first component of the default value of the `runtimepath` option is the `vimfiles` directory I want.

However, I have no idea how to extract the *first* component from `rtp`. This, again, seems like it should be trivial, but `&rtp[0]` expands to the first *character* of the runtimepath, because apparently `&rtp` is actually a string, even though it's clearly semantically a list (!!?).

So...how do I get the first component of the runtimepath? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I use the `$VIMFILES` variable both to set up `rtp` and `path` for Vundle and to set `undodir` for persistent undo. Without such a variable, I'd need vimfile-directory-finding logic in both of those parts of my Vim setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it:

```
set rtp&
let $VIMFILES=split(&rtp,",")[0]
```

Still seems overly manual, but it's not as ugly as I feared.